# $u_{xx}+u_x=f(x)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> $$u_{xx}+u_x=f(x) , \quad x\in (0,l), \quad
>  u(0)=u'(0)=\frac{1}{2}[u'(l)+u(l)]. $$
>
> **1)** Is the solution unique? ($f$ is a given function).
>
> **2)** Under what condition on f does a solution exist?

Answers:

**1)** No.

**2)** $\int_0^l f(x) \ dx = 0.$

Since we only have partial derivatives w.r.t $x$ only the above translates into a linear non-homogenous second order ODE. Ofcourse I can't solve it generally since I don't know the shape of $f$ in order to make a proper anzats for the particular solution.

Anyone who can explain how they came to the answers? On 2), the answer seems to hint at using the method of integrating factors, however in my single variable course we only used that method for first order ODEs.

Comment: To answer $2$, you can use the Fredholm alternative if you have learnt it. Also, are you supposed to have _three_ conditions for a _second_ order ODE?

Comment: No I have not learnt it unfortunately. No, the degree of the equation indicates the number of conditions needed for the solution to be unique. So for 1), I do have 2 conditions yet the answer is no.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

When you are solving $y'' + y' = f(x)$, make a substitution $z = y'$ to end up with $z'+z = f(x)$ which is a first order ODE and apply integrating factor.

The LHS should become $\frac{d}{dx} \left[ e^x z(x) \right]$.

Comment: LHS should become that if you multiply by $e^x$.

Comment: Ok I see what you did there. So there is no other way to do this without using the integrating factor? Also, how do I know that the solution is not unique without going through your hint?

Comment: @Parseval You can solve the homogeneous 2nd order ODE, and depending on the actual $f(x)$ you may guess a particular solution, that would also work.

Answer (score 1):

$$u_{xx}+u_x=f(x) , \quad x\in (0,l), \quad
 u(0)=u'(0)=\frac{1}{2}[u'(l)+u(l)].$$
You can treat this DE like a first order DE with $u_x(x)$ as $y(x)$ and integrate with integrating factor method:
$$(u_{x}e^x)'=f(x)e^x$$
Integrating:
$$\int_0^l(u_{x}e^x)'dx=\int_0^l f(x)e^xdx$$
$$(u_{x}(l)e^l)-u_{x}(0)e^0=\int_0^l f(x)e^xdx$$
$$u_{x}(l)e^l-u_{x}(0)=\int_0^l f(x)e^xdx$$
$$u_{x}(l)e^l-\frac 12 (u_{x}(l)+u(l))=\int_0^l f(x)e^xdx$$
$$\boxed {u_{x}(l)\left(e^l-\frac 12 \right )-\frac 12 u(l)=\int_0^l f(x)e^xdx}$$

Comment: Yes this was the answer I got too. But why do I conclude that $$\int_{0}^{l}f(x) \ dx =0$$